# Is there an App to automatically forward SMS to email?

Tags: sms

Is there an app that automatically get all the SMS received on a Windows Phone and forward them in my email?

iPhone has an option to do that and Android has Apps that can do this task. Can I do this as well on a Lumia 730?

Answer (score 4):

Not possible under the official APIs for Windows Phone. In a (misguided, IMO) attempt to keep things like SMS super-secure, Microsoft doesn't allow third-party apps to access the SMS store or receive notifications when they arrive. The APIs (and capabilities to use them) do exist, but the APIs are not (publicly) documented and third-party developers are not permitted to declare the required capabilities in their apps (the store will reject them, and phones won't let you sideload them without hacking the phone a bit).

Windows 10 Mobile may improve this situation somewhat - if nothing else, it's already much easier to sideload apps, and they've loosened up the capabilities usable by third-party devs a bit - but so far such an app doesn't exist (to my knowledge).

The other hope, of course, would be for an OEM (or Microsoft themselves, as part of the OS / as a first-party app) to release such an app. You could try requesting this on [the uservoice site](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions).

Answer (score 0):

This may be changing soon as Microsoft has opened up an SMS API via `Windows.Devices.sms`, as seen in [this official example app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive).

However, it is still locked down to special permissions, however it's easier to request this permission by 3rd party developers if their app/app idea is trusted enough. So, you may see some new, trusted, SMS based apps after the release of Windows 10 Mobile (emphasis on "may")